# Is category theory a way to talk about isomorphic structures?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose I have drawn each complex number as an object (a node of a graph), and I have connected the objects by arrows, which are also labelled by complex numbers. If $a$ and $c$ are connected by the arrow $b$, then it means $a*b = c$.

I could also draw an isomorphic graph using $(2 \times 2)$-matrices. So I can say that both graphs represent the same mathematical structure.

**But** the idea of isomorphisms existed before category theory. Groups and their representations also carry the same idea, as in, different representations are the same algebra. In what way does category theory generalise/expand on this idea?

Comment: Your actual question feeld somewhat detached from your first two paragraphs. It also feels far too broad. It sounds like "The idea of equality existed before modern algebra. What does ring theory add to this idea?"

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I have edited it. I'm genuinely interested in how exactly Category theory expanded on this idea. To me, it seems like representation theory is as general as this idea gets. I can't think of any expansion.

Comment: See [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorification+in+representation+theory): "Approaches to categorification vary but generally involve replacing set-theoretic statements by their category-theoretic analogues. Sets become categories, functions become functors, and equations become natural isomorphisms. In many cases, this process leads to the appearance of structures not previously observed."

Comment: “Please no jargon”: have you seen anything about category theory? The concepts are so general that you need very specific language to describe what it’s about. Regardless, this thread feels somewhat relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288900/what-are-the-importance-and-power-of-category-theory .

Comment: One minor quibble:  a representation of a group doesn't necessarily have the same algebra.  It is an image of the group but not necessarily a complete one.  Only a faithful representation (i.e. an injection into the relevant general linear group) preserves the entire multiplicative structure.

Answer (score 2):

I'll preface this by warning that I'm no expert in Category theory.  However, I'll offer a few comments and thoughts which I hope will prove helpful.  Since you sound like you want a high-level view, this answer will have more verbiage than equations.

Category theory generalizes the notion of isomorphism in a number of ways because it offers a number of distinct isomorphism-like concepts.

Between objects in a category, an isomorphism consists of two arrows in opposite directions which compose to the relevant identities.  This captures the notion of bijection in SET or algebraic isomorphism in GRP or MON or homeomorphism in TOP, etc.  However, in category theory objects need not be set-based and arrows need not represent maps.  As such, an isomorphism between objects need not correspond to our usual intuition for such things.

There also are a number of notions of isomorphism at the level of categories themselves.  Here is where it gets interesting.  In this case, we really are dealing with CAT, the category of small categories (where "small" just is a qualifier to avoid certain Russell-style issues which demand lots of technical attention).  Here, the objects are categories and the arrows are functors.

Note that this also can have direct application to your algebraic example because groups and monoids can be viewed as categories --- each with a single object and with the arrows representing the group or monoid elements.  Functors then correspond to homomorphisms.

At the category level there are a number of distinct notions of equivalence.  It turns out that isomorphism in the traditional sense (i.e. the one mentioned earlier) is the least useful of these.  One of the great insights of category theory is that adjointness can be a much more interesting relationship.  The key components involved are:

Natural transformation:  given two functors $f,g:A\rightarrow B$ between the same categories (and in the same direction), a way of transforming the image of one into the image of the other.  It assigns to each object $a$ in category $A$ an arrow in category $B$ which goes from $f(a)\rightarrow g(a)$.

Natural isomorphism:  each of the arrows in the natural transformation (i.e. the $f(a)\rightarrow g(a)$ above) actually is an isomorphism (i.e. has an inverse $g(a)\rightarrow f(a)$ which composes to give the relevant identities.   [Technically, we can regard the functors $A\rightarrow B$ as a category, with the natural transformations as arrows and the natural isomorphisms as the isomorphisms (this may not be obvious from the def I provided, but it turns out to be true)]. One standard example is $Vect\rightarrow Vect$, where $f(V)=V$ and $g(V)=V^{**}$ for any vector space $V$.  $V$ and $V^{**}$ are naturally isomorphic in the sense that every vector has a natural double-dual defined by $v^{**}(w^*)= w^*(v)$ for all $w^*\in V^*$, as opposed to $V$ and $V^*$ being isomorphic but having no preferred isomorphism and thus requiring additional info (usually a choice of basis) to favor one isomorphism over another.

I think that's the minimum jargon needed for the rest.

Suppose we have two categories $A$ and $B$.  In decreasing order of strictness and increasing order of utility, we have the following concepts.  Each requires a pair of functors $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$.

1. Isomorphism:  $f\circ g= Id_B$ and $g\circ f= Id_A$.  This just is an isomorphism in the sense described earlier, but on the category CAT.
2. Equivalence:  $f\circ g\approx Id_B$ and $g\circ f\approx Id_A$  (with $\approx$ denoting a natural isomorphism between the functors).
3. Adjoint:  There are natural transforms $\epsilon:f\circ g\rightarrow Id_B$ and $\eta:Id_A\rightarrow g\circ f$ which obey certain conditions (which basically say that we get the same result by following different paths). Equivalently, for every pair of objects $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$, there is a bijection between the set of arrows $f(a)\rightarrow b$ and the set of arrows $a\rightarrow g(b)$ (which also must obey certain "naturality" conditions).

I think it would not be inaccurate to say that the most important way Category theory generalizes the notion of isomorphism is to adjoint functors.

Of course, this is a vast oversimplification written by a beginner and is just meant to give a general overview.  If you're interested in learning more, I highly recommend Leinster's thin and quite accessible book.